# HTTPS hostname wrong: should be <xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx>, checkURLSpoofing. What is the host name being passed?

Tags: java, web-services, ssl

The error I am receiving is

```
com.sun.xml.ws.client.ClientTransportException: HTTP transport error: java.io.IOException: HTTPS hostname wrong:  should be <xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx>
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.checkURLSpoofing(HttpsClient.java:524)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:448)
```

The question I have is, how can I get the value that is being passed to checkURLSpoofing? My intention is to reroute it in my hosts file. I am already using this block of code to prevent Hostname Verification, though I believe it is still happening.

```
 HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier()
 {
     public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session)
     {               
         return true;
     }
 });
```

I have also added this to my run configuration to prevent Hostname Verification

`-Dweblogic.security.SSL.ignoreHostnameVerification=true`

I also do not have the option of altering the SSL certificate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the hosts file entry was being overridden by the proxy I was behind. Solved the issue by going off site.